# Specific compilation flags with autotools and static library

Tags: automake, compiler-flags

TL;DR: When I compile an external library with a specific set of flags, how can I deal with warnings triggered by the flags used to compile my own code when I include the headers of this library ?

I am using autotools as a build system in a project and I would like to set compilation flags properly depending on the target.

I would like to compile my own sources with a somehow high level of warning (any help from the compiler to debug / prevent bugs  is always welcome).
In the warning flags set currently used there is `-Wsuggest-override` which I'll take as an example.

I have besides my sources an external library (`pugixml` if you really want to know) which I would like to compile with, let's say `-Ofast`

To have two separate sets of flags,
In the info page of `automake` there is an interesting section with a concrete example [Per-Object Flags: How to simulate per-object flags?](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Per_002dObject-Flags.html).
(There are also some SO question on the topic)

That's why in my `Makefile.am` there is the following:

```
__top_srcdir__bin_LDADD = libpugixml.a
noinst_LIBRARIES = libpugixml.a
libpugixml_a_SOURCES = pugixml/pugixml.cpp
libpugixml_a_CPPFLAGS = -Ofast
```

The set of program sources no longer contains the library sources:

```
__top_srcdir__we_SOURCES = main.cc
```

This works fine, the library is build with a set of flags, my sources with another one, everything is ok...

Until I include a header of the library in my sources and that's why I'm posting this (too long ?) question

main.cc:

```
#include <pugixml/pugixml.hpp> // -Wsuggest-override triggered

int main() { return 0; }
```

During the compilation, the `-Wsuggest-override` is triggered in the library sources

Does the official `automake` solution to have different sets of warnings not not apply in this case or am I doing something wrong ?

I am not sure if it matters but I'm using `g++` and/or `clang` (depending on the mood)
the `automake` version: automake (GNU automake) 1.15

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wsuggest-override"
#include <pugixml/pugixml.hpp>
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

...

Is what I usually would do in these instances with `clang`.

I don't see how this is an `automake` problem.  You're compiling the convenience library without elevated warnings, and the code that uses the dependency header with elevated warnings.  You'd have the same problem if you built them using just `make`, or `cmake`, or the command line.

Comment: +1, Thank you for your answer. I was wondering if there is not a way to tell automake "this header belongs to this library so if it's included, use the appropriate flags"

Comment: OK, I see what you are getting at now.  Unfortunately, the answer is no, `automake` can't do that.